# Error.pm a Perl module and I'm trying to add template functionality to it so I can use placeholders instead of variables throughout my ErrorLibrary.pm

Tags: perl, hashmap, template-toolkit

I want to make it function so that variable values which are retrieved during a build (at runtime) can be inserted in place of template placeholders from the message field of an Error hash in ErrorLibrary.pm. I know how to use template toolkit (sort of). Do I have to call the template process method in the code where the error occurs. (I included an example of an error occuring in the code below also) . I hope I have explained what I want to achieve here.

Error.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package ASC::Builder::Error;

use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/new/;

use Template;
use ASC::Builder::ErrorLibrary;




use overload
    '""'  => \&stringify;


# this method should handle both the old and new type error messages
sub new {

    my ($package, $first_param) = (shift,shift);


    if (ref $first_param eq 'HASH') {
        my %params = @_;
        return bless { 
            message => $first_param->{message}, # contextual message in some cases which will contain runtime  parameters
            code => $first_param->{code},
            errorNum => $first_param->{errorNum} ,
            category =>$first_param->{category} ,
            tt => $first_param->{tt}, 
            fatal => $first_param->{fatal}, 
            wiki_page => $first_param->{wiki_page}, 
            %params}, $package;
    }
    else {
        my %params = @_; 
        return bless {
            message => $first_param,
            %params}, $package;

}   
}

sub message { shift->{message} }

sub details {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{details} || $self->{message};
}

sub tt { shift->{tt} }

sub code { shift->{code} }

sub errorNum { shift->{errorNum} }

sub category { shift->{category} }

sub fatal { shift->{fatal} }

sub wiki_page { shift->{wiki_page} }


sub stringify {
    my $self = shift;
    return sprintf('Error("%s")', ( $self->message ) ); # removed or $self->fatal
}

# Used to deserialize from build json.
sub recreate_from_hash {
    my ($package, $hash) = @_;
    return bless $hash, $package;
}

# Use to check if something is our error.
sub is_error {
    if (scalar(@_) > 1) { # Called as package->is_error
        shift; # Get rid of package
    }
    return UNIVERSAL::isa(shift, 'ASC::Builder::Error');
}

# create template for contextual messages for errors
$template->process(\$first_param->{message}, $vars);
```

ErrorLibrary.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::ErrorLibrary;

use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Exporter';

# list of export error messages
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/

UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR
/;  

# error message list

use constant {

    UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR => {
        code => "UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR",
        errorNum => 727,
        category => 'Switch Error',
        message => "Could not ping switch [% switch_ip %] in [% timeout %] seconds.",
        tt => {template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://www.server-build.com/index.php/ErrorCodes/UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
    }

};

1;
```

Example of how and error is handled in the code:
`

```
# this prints out the message field of the error hash
die ASC::Builder::Error->new(UNABLE_PING_SWITCH_ERROR);
```

I want it to be able to insert the variable values for `$switch_ip` and `$timeout` in place of `[% switch_ip %]` and `[% timeout %]`. I know I if they variables I am dealing with it wern't located in various parts throughout the code I could create a list of all the variables and use the template process function.

Do I add the template process function to the Error.pm file and then call it throughout the code wherever an error occurs. I am so confused, been stuck on this for quite a while. Any help would be much appreciated.

Again, apologies if there is anything wrong with how I asked the question or how it is phrased. Thanks.

Comment: Hello again. When do you want the TT to render your message? Probably Template is a bit overkill, but if I remember correctly you can't introduce new dependencies, right?

Comment: If you are around, maybe we should have a little chat (which I'm trying to setup now). I'll talk you through some basics.

Comment: I managed to come up with an approach of my own.. but I need a bit of help developing it further . Here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771368/a-method-which-inserts-template-placeholders-into-a-string-which-is-a-key-in-a-h)